# How to install Zendframework-2 in wampserver?

Tags: zend-framework2

i already install **git, and composer.exe** now i try to install **zendframework-2** but it not work please provide **rightway** for **installing zend framework-2**.
please provide me right **tutorial or video** for install proper.

Comment: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/installation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to install ZF2 as a library but that's not what I recommend. I think it's best to install ZF2 in every project from composer.phar. This makes it easier to master the updates of applications in production.

For ZF2, install the `skeleton` application that allows you to set up your project. This installation sets up ZF2 complete.

- Make sure your `Windows` path contains `php.exe` and `composer.bat`
  paths ;
- Run in console : `php "path\to\composer.phar" create-project -sdev --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application "directory/of/your/project"`

For ZF3, follow : https://framework.zend.com/downloads